# Android- write system settings UI alternative

Tags: java, android

My Android app currently enables WRITE_SETTINGS in its Manifest. When the app makes an intent Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, it shows a system dialog enabling the user to set the permission for the app to modify system settings. I would like to change this dialog however because I do not like the layout of the system generated screen. In addition, I would like to enable battery optimization on the app as well, and that has its own separate system dialog. The system dialog takes up the whole screen and can be confusing for the user to use, especially when there are two screens displayed in succession.

I would like to use my own XML layout or a popup for the dialog and letting the user enable/disable these permissions as needed. Is there a way to do that and not have the app launch the system dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the system dialog for settings, media projection, runtime permissions... It's a system dialog, it can't be changed to prevent abuse.

The best you can do is explain to the user what's expected of them before you start showing these system dialogs.

> The system dialog [...] can be confusing for the user to use, especially when there are two screens displayed in succession.

**Explain what needs to happen before each step.**

Explain what you need from the user in your app, in your visual style, then show one system dialog.
After user confirms it explain the next thing in your app, then show another system dialog.

[Avast Anti-Theft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.at_play) (not affiliated) uses this approach when setting the app - it needs to enable its device admin and listen for notifications, both are controlled in system UI.

Comment: Well that is dumb. At least allow for customization or adding things to the screen. Users want a good UI and a smooth experience, and this can be achieved while still maintaining security requirements by explicitly asking them their permission.